# Eclipse CDT: Include from deeper directories e.g. include/%PRJ%/%PRJ%/*.hpp by only specifying top level dir

Tags: eclipse-cdt, ros2

Say there's a library suite where the header files per package are installed 2 directories away from the top level of the library suite's include directory. So

```
|- include
  |- pkg-a
    |- pkg-a
      |- aa.hpp
      |- ab.hpp
  |- pkg-b
    |- pkg-b
      |- ba.hpp
      |- bb.hpp
```

But there's existing C++ codebase that uses `#include <pkg-a/aa.hpp>` to reference those headers.

## Question

Is there a way in Eclipse CDT to specify a single (or as few as possible) path so that the existing C++ codes can continue to reference those headers?

### Background

The frame work (*1) seems to have changed the way headers are installed in a newer version. While (I haven't verified but I assume) its building environment seems to internally adjust to this extra layer of directories, IDEs have no idea about the change so the existing code base started failing to reference, with a single path to the top directory of the header suite `/x/y/include` set in Project's properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> GNU C++.

*1...Version of ROS2 called Humble (ref. [ros2_documentation#3702](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/3702))

### Env

Eclipse CDT 2023-03 on Ubuntu 22.04